# How can you fill combobox in vb.net with column name from Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datatable, combobox, sqlcommand

How to fill combobox in vb.net with column name from Microsoft Sql Server? I have table name called Table_Categories. I wish to fill the combobox with the column names of that table . I am also planning on adding column names in the table using vb.net as its front end . how can I do it ?

```
    Public Sub Categories()
    Dim Connect As New SqlConnection
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim DataTable As New System.Data.DataTable
    Dim Query As String
    ConnectionString = "Data Source=LUSPOC-PC;Initial Catalog=Sales_Invnetory;Integrated Security=True"
    Connect = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Connect.Open()
    Connect.ChangeDatabase("Sales_Inventory")
    Query = "select Column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='Table_Categories'"
    Adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(Query, Connect)

    Adapter.Fill(DataTable)
    Admin.items_category_combobx.DataSource = DataTable
    Admin.items_category_combobx.DisplayMember = "Column_name"
    Admin.items_category_combobx.ValueMember = "Column_name"

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us some effort. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried doing this

Comment: Please avoid using the comments to write code. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Don't put it as a comment. Put that in your post to help improve your question so people can help you better.

Comment: ok thanks. Im new at this ,sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Connect.ChangeDatabase("database-name")    
Query = "select Column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='your-Table-name'"
    Admin.items_category_combobx.DataSource = DataTable
    Admin.items_category_combobx.DisplayMember = "Column_name"
    Admin.items_category_combobx.ValueMember = "Column_name"
```

Change your query as above and you will get column names in your dataset. For adding column, take column name and type from user. build and execute an `alter table` query for adding column from it.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I edited my question with the Query use sent . for you to see how I use it . is that correct ?

Comment: set displaymember and valuemember to "column_name". You have set it incorrectly

Comment: check my modified answer

Comment: you mean the rest are correct already ? I already change it to Column_name ,still nothing happens . by the way Im a module , do i need to put it on the combobox ?

Comment: datasource should be datatable not adapter. Yes these properties are of combobox

Comment: Adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() is not required Adapter,Fill will get the data for you

Comment: thanks I already did what you said , but still my combobox is Empty

Comment: try running the query directly against the database where the table is present and see if you are getting any results.

Comment: the result is Empty

Comment: thats why you are not able to see any items in drop down. check if table name is correct or not. check if it exists in the database against which you are running the query. add "USE <database-name>" statement before running the query also.

Comment: I can see the Column names in the Result already when I use the "USE <database-name>" but I run query on the database Directly , how can do this in vb.net ?

Comment: In vb.net connection string set value of target database to your database

Comment: can you write it as a syntax ? I dont get it . please ?

Comment: add a line of code before query variable as given in my modified answer

Comment: I already modified the code as what you have said. but still nothing .

Comment: Please share the value of variable "ConnectionString".

Comment: The ConnectionString there is my Connection to the Database

Comment: "LUSPOC-PC":-- Is this the name of PC for database server?

Comment: Yes it is. I copied it from the Dialog box of SQL SERVER

Comment: correct your database name in connection string. Is it "Sales_Invnetory" or "Sales_Inventory"?

Answer (score 0):

```
          Using sqlconn As New SqlConnection("your connection string")
                sqlconn.Open()
                Using SqlCommand As New SqlCommand("select Column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='Table_Categories'", sqlconn)
                    SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0                     
                    Using sqlAdp As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand)
                        sqlAdp.Fill(dt)
                    End Using
                End Using
        End Using
        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
        ComboBox1.DataTextField = "Column_name" 
        ComboBox1.DataValueField = "Column_name"
        ComboBox1.DataBind()
```

Comment: do i have to declare DataTextField,DataValueField,DataBind() ? its not working

Comment: how ? Im new at this .