# How to Fill ComboBox with DataTable Column Names in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I need to fill a combobox on a form with the column names from an existing data table. I don't want to manually enter the column names in case they change in the future. I also want to keep my code tidy, so I don't want a standard loop. How can I fill a combobox with the column names most efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264180/how-can-you-fill-combobox-in-vb-net-with-column-name-from-microsoft-sql-server), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026285/get-all-column-names-of-a-datatable-into-string-array-using-linq-predicate), and [here](http://vb.net-informations.com/dataset/bind-combobox.htm), I was able to piece together the following LINQ query and set it directly to the data source on the combobox when the form loads.

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    comboBox.DataSource = (From dc In dataTable.Columns
                             Select dc.ColumnName).ToArray()
End Sub
```